# Fade in/out in between fades

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

so here is the thing. I saw this website: http://laneandassociates.co/english-mustard-scottish-oats and I absolutely can't figure out how they do their fades.

The great thing about their fade effect is, that it can be "stopped" in the middle of the fading process by clicking.

For a better understanding: Let's assume the fadeIn duration is 1000. If I click when the fadeIn is at (for example) 700, the fadeIn immediately stops at 700 and begins to fade back out to 0. Then the fadeIn of the next image starts from 0. It just looks really smooth.

Problem is, I can't even find the code for the fades. Can someone show me how they made it, so I can take a look at it and learn it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using browser dev tools (ex. Chrome F12)? It appears that each item is an <article> element with a class of "slide". The slide is using a CSS transition on opacity with a cubic-bezier definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site is using a **cubic-bezier** CSS animation.

This is achieved with some CSS like the following:

```
.element.animated {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1),transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1),visibility 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The hard part can be calculating the correct parameters for the type of animation you want. You can use [this site to do that](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67).

Here is a [demo of another animation](http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-cubic-bezier/#).

---

For removing animation on hover:

```
.element.animated:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The question was more about how to stop the fade in the middel of fading. But to make it smooth, I will take a look a the cubic-bazier, so thank you for that!

Comment: @user2626784 actually, you can stop the fade by removing the `animated` class when it's hovered over - added to my answer.

Please mark the answer as correct / up-vote if it helped you :)

Comment: I did ;-) thank you again for the help! maybe it also helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So one way you can do fading with jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/. You can use the `fadeIn` method to fade in an element and the `fadeOut` method to fade out an element. To make the element stop fading on a click you could do something like this:

```
$('mySelector').on('click', function() {
    myElement.stop(); // This stops the fade from continuing
});
```

By using the `stop` method you can pause an animation or complete it early. For more details on `stop` animation check out the docs here: https://api.jquery.com/stop/.

Comment: I found a way to accomplish it through CSS only. But thanks to your post I was able to come to a solution. So Thanks!